Understanding derivation of commutator for Dirac Field
Im going through Peskin and Shroeder's book on QFT, in the chapter about the Dirac Equation. They are trying to teach why quantizing with the commutator is wrong, and I'm trying to follow the calculations. When it comes to the expression of the commutator itself:
$$\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \sum_{s=1,2} \left( a_{\mathbf{p}}^s u^s(\mathbf{p}) + b_{-\mathbf{p}}^s v^s(-\mathbf{p}) \right)$$
where $a_{\mathbf{p}}^s$ and $b_{\mathbf{p}}^s$ are operator coefficients. However, shouldn't the quantity be $b_{\mathbf{-p}}^{s\dagger}$, as was the case in the Klein-Gordon Field?
Anyways, the expression that I'm trying to verify is the commutation relation (3.86) for $\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger$. The following is the first line for expression 3.89:
$$
[\psi(\mathbf{x}), \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{y})] = \int \frac{d^3 p d^3 q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}} 2E_{\mathbf{q}}}} e^{i (\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{y})} 
\times \sum_{r,s} \left( [a_{\mathbf{p}}^r, a_{\mathbf{q}}^{s\dagger}] u^r(\mathbf{p}) \bar{u}^s(\mathbf{q}) + [b_{-\mathbf{p}}^r, b_{-\mathbf{q}}^{s\dagger}] v^r(-\mathbf{p}) \bar{v}^s(-\mathbf{q}) \right) \gamma^0$$
When multiplying through and finding the commutator, it seems like I can only reach the desired result if I could move the a's and b's freely with the u's and b's. However, I don't understand why these quantities should commute. I know that the u's and v's are matrices, and the a's and b's operators, but I just don't understand why they commute. Why is that?

Only operators have issues with commutation or anti commutation. Spinors are just part of the classical solutions of the equations. They can be moved around without any issue.

This has been asked so many times before on this site. Please use the search function.

This question is similar to: Does the creation/annihilation operator commute with the spinors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please don't change the question in its content. Instead, ask a new question.
